# Heroku doesn't install dependencies from Pipfile, but works with requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku

With dependencies held in the pipfile, occasionally a random module missing error would pop up, eventually heroku seemed to just stop installing the dependencies at all:

*build log:*

```
-----> Installing python-3.7.8
-----> Installing pip 9.0.2, setuptools 39.0.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (290023)…
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Running post-compile hook
-----> Collecting static files for django-compressor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 26, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
-----> Compressing JS/CSS files via django-compressor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 26, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
-----> Collecting static files after django-compressor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 26, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

as soon as I extracted the dependencies into a requirements.txt file and deleted the pipfile, everythihng worked fine.

Now I did have both a pipfile and a requirements.txt file at the same time at some point by accident, and I read that that could cause problems, but I dealt with that and nothing happened.

Help would be appreciated, as I would prefer to use pipenv and not keep having to dump out the dependencies.

EDIT:
*Pipfile*

```
[[source]]  
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"  
verify_ssl = true   
name = "pypi"   

[packages]  
Django = "*"    
django-split-settings = "*" 
python-dotenv = "*" 
django-compressor = "*" 
django-libsass = "*"    
Brotli = "*"    
django-htmlmin = "*"    
gunicorn = "*"  
dj-database-url = "*"   
wagtail = "*"   
wagtail-metadata = "*"  
wagtail-blocks = "*"    
psycopg2 = "*"  
django-tz-detect = "*"  
wagtailcodeblock = "*"  
django-taggit = "*" 
django-taggit-templatetags2 = "*"   
django-fontawesome-5 = "*"  
django-debug-toolbar = "*"  
wagtail-robots = "*"    
wand = "*"  

[dev-packages]  
pylint = "*"    
django-debug-toolbar = "*"  

[requires]  
python_version = "3.7"  

[packages.whitenoise]   
extras = [ "brotli",]   

[packages.django-storages]  
extras = [ "dropbox",]
```

*Pipfile.lock*

```
{   
    "_meta": {  
        "hash": {   
            "sha256": "729acd086f631676263953529c931732010fe3bce1070129fe4c5a178c290023"    
        },  
        "pipfile-spec": 6,  
        "requires": {   
            "python_version": "3.7" 
        },  
        "sources": [    
            {   
                "name": "pypi", 
                "url": "https://pypi.python.org/simple",    
                "verify_ssl": true  
            }   
        ]   
    },  
    "default": {    
        "django-storages": {    
            "extras": [ 
                "dropbox"   
            ]   
        },  
        "whitenoise": { 
            "extras": [ 
                "brotli"    
            ]   
        }   
    },  
    "develop": {    
        "asgiref": {    
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:7e51911ee147dd685c3c8b805c0ad0cb58d360987b56953878f8c06d2d1c6f1a",  
                "sha256:9fc6fb5d39b8af147ba40765234fa822b39818b12cc80b35ad9b0cef3a476aed"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",   
            "version": "==3.2.10"   
        },  
        "astroid": {    
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:2f4078c2a41bf377eea06d71c9d2ba4eb8f6b1af2135bec27bbbb7d8f12bb703",  
                "sha256:bc58d83eb610252fd8de6363e39d4f1d0619c894b0ed24603b881c02e64c7386"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",   
            "version": "==2.4.2"    
        },  
        "colorama": {   
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:7d73d2a99753107a36ac6b455ee49046802e59d9d076ef8e47b61499fa29afff",  
                "sha256:e96da0d330793e2cb9485e9ddfd918d456036c7149416295932478192f4436a1"   
            ],  
            "markers": "sys_platform == 'win32'",   
            "version": "==0.4.3"    
        },  
        "django": { 
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:31a5fbbea5fc71c99e288ec0b2f00302a0a92c44b13ede80b73a6a4d6d205582",  
                "sha256:5457fc953ec560c5521b41fad9e6734a4668b7ba205832191bbdff40ec61073c"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.6'",   
            "version": "==3.0.8"    
        },  
        "django-debug-toolbar": {   
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:eabbefe89881bbe4ca7c980ff102e3c35c8e8ad6eb725041f538988f2f39a943",  
                "sha256:ff94725e7aae74b133d0599b9bf89bd4eb8f5d2c964106e61d11750228c8774c"   
            ],  
            "index": "pypi",    
            "version": "==2.2"  
        },  
        "isort": {  
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:54da7e92468955c4fceacd0c86bd0ec997b0e1ee80d97f67c35a78b719dccab1",  
                "sha256:6e811fcb295968434526407adb8796944f1988c5b65e8139058f2014cbe100fd"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'",    
            "version": "==4.3.21"   
        },  
        "lazy-object-proxy": {  
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:0c4b206227a8097f05c4dbdd323c50edf81f15db3b8dc064d08c62d37e1a504d",  
                "sha256:194d092e6f246b906e8f70884e620e459fc54db3259e60cf69a4d66c3fda3449",  
                "sha256:1be7e4c9f96948003609aa6c974ae59830a6baecc5376c25c92d7d697e684c08",  
                "sha256:4677f594e474c91da97f489fea5b7daa17b5517190899cf213697e48d3902f5a",  
                "sha256:48dab84ebd4831077b150572aec802f303117c8cc5c871e182447281ebf3ac50",  
                "sha256:5541cada25cd173702dbd99f8e22434105456314462326f06dba3e180f203dfd",  
                "sha256:59f79fef100b09564bc2df42ea2d8d21a64fdcda64979c0fa3db7bdaabaf6239",  
                "sha256:8d859b89baf8ef7f8bc6b00aa20316483d67f0b1cbf422f5b4dc56701c8f2ffb",  
                "sha256:9254f4358b9b541e3441b007a0ea0764b9d056afdeafc1a5569eee1cc6c1b9ea",  
                "sha256:9651375199045a358eb6741df3e02a651e0330be090b3bc79f6d0de31a80ec3e",  
                "sha256:97bb5884f6f1cdce0099f86b907aa41c970c3c672ac8b9c8352789e103cf3156",  
                "sha256:9b15f3f4c0f35727d3a0fba4b770b3c4ebbb1fa907dbcc046a1d2799f3edd142",  
                "sha256:a2238e9d1bb71a56cd710611a1614d1194dc10a175c1e08d75e1a7bcc250d442",  
                "sha256:a6ae12d08c0bf9909ce12385803a543bfe99b95fe01e752536a60af2b7797c62",  
                "sha256:ca0a928a3ddbc5725be2dd1cf895ec0a254798915fb3a36af0964a0a4149e3db",  
                "sha256:cb2c7c57005a6804ab66f106ceb8482da55f5314b7fcb06551db1edae4ad1531",  
                "sha256:d74bb8693bf9cf75ac3b47a54d716bbb1a92648d5f781fc799347cfc95952383",  
                "sha256:d945239a5639b3ff35b70a88c5f2f491913eb94871780ebfabb2568bd58afc5a",  
                "sha256:eba7011090323c1dadf18b3b689845fd96a61ba0a1dfbd7f24b921398affc357",  
                "sha256:efa1909120ce98bbb3777e8b6f92237f5d5c8ea6758efea36a473e1d38f7d3e4",  
                "sha256:f3900e8a5de27447acbf900b4750b0ddfd7ec1ea7fbaf11dfa911141bc522af0"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'",    
            "version": "==1.4.3"    
        },  
        "mccabe": { 
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:ab8a6258860da4b6677da4bd2fe5dc2c659cff31b3ee4f7f5d64e79735b80d42",  
                "sha256:dd8d182285a0fe56bace7f45b5e7d1a6ebcbf524e8f3bd87eb0f125271b8831f"   
            ],  
            "version": "==0.6.1"    
        },  
        "pylint": { 
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:7dd78437f2d8d019717dbf287772d0b2dbdfd13fc016aa7faa08d67bccc46adc",  
                "sha256:d0ece7d223fe422088b0e8f13fa0a1e8eb745ebffcb8ed53d3e95394b6101a1c"   
            ],  
            "index": "pypi",    
            "version": "==2.5.3"    
        },  
        "pytz": {   
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:a494d53b6d39c3c6e44c3bec237336e14305e4f29bbf800b599253057fbb79ed",  
                "sha256:c35965d010ce31b23eeb663ed3cc8c906275d6be1a34393a1d73a41febf4a048"   
            ],  
            "version": "==2020.1"   
        },  
        "six": {    
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:30639c035cdb23534cd4aa2dd52c3bf48f06e5f4a941509c8bafd8ce11080259",  
                "sha256:8b74bedcbbbaca38ff6d7491d76f2b06b3592611af620f8426e82dddb04a5ced"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'",    
            "version": "==1.15.0"   
        },  
        "sqlparse": {   
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:022fb9c87b524d1f7862b3037e541f68597a730a8843245c349fc93e1643dc4e",  
                "sha256:e162203737712307dfe78860cc56c8da8a852ab2ee33750e33aeadf38d12c548"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'",    
            "version": "==0.3.1"    
        },  
        "toml": {   
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:926b612be1e5ce0634a2ca03470f95169cf16f939018233a670519cb4ac58b0f",  
                "sha256:bda89d5935c2eac546d648028b9901107a595863cb36bae0c73ac804a9b4ce88"   
            ],  
            "version": "==0.10.1"   
        },  
        "typed-ast": {  
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:0666aa36131496aed8f7be0410ff974562ab7eeac11ef351def9ea6fa28f6355",  
                "sha256:0c2c07682d61a629b68433afb159376e24e5b2fd4641d35424e462169c0a7919",  
                "sha256:249862707802d40f7f29f6e1aad8d84b5aa9e44552d2cc17384b209f091276aa",  
                "sha256:24995c843eb0ad11a4527b026b4dde3da70e1f2d8806c99b7b4a7cf491612652",  
                "sha256:269151951236b0f9a6f04015a9004084a5ab0d5f19b57de779f908621e7d8b75",  
                "sha256:4083861b0aa07990b619bd7ddc365eb7fa4b817e99cf5f8d9cf21a42780f6e01",  
                "sha256:498b0f36cc7054c1fead3d7fc59d2150f4d5c6c56ba7fb150c013fbc683a8d2d",  
                "sha256:4e3e5da80ccbebfff202a67bf900d081906c358ccc3d5e3c8aea42fdfdfd51c1",  
                "sha256:6daac9731f172c2a22ade6ed0c00197ee7cc1221aa84cfdf9c31defeb059a907",  
                "sha256:715ff2f2df46121071622063fc7543d9b1fd19ebfc4f5c8895af64a77a8c852c",  
                "sha256:73d785a950fc82dd2a25897d525d003f6378d1cb23ab305578394694202a58c3",  
                "sha256:8c8aaad94455178e3187ab22c8b01a3837f8ee50e09cf31f1ba129eb293ec30b",  
                "sha256:8ce678dbaf790dbdb3eba24056d5364fb45944f33553dd5869b7580cdbb83614",  
                "sha256:aaee9905aee35ba5905cfb3c62f3e83b3bec7b39413f0a7f19be4e547ea01ebb",  
                "sha256:bcd3b13b56ea479b3650b82cabd6b5343a625b0ced5429e4ccad28a8973f301b",  
                "sha256:c9e348e02e4d2b4a8b2eedb48210430658df6951fa484e59de33ff773fbd4b41",  
                "sha256:d205b1b46085271b4e15f670058ce182bd1199e56b317bf2ec004b6a44f911f6",  
                "sha256:d43943ef777f9a1c42bf4e552ba23ac77a6351de620aa9acf64ad54933ad4d34",  
                "sha256:d5d33e9e7af3b34a40dc05f498939f0ebf187f07c385fd58d591c533ad8562fe",  
                "sha256:fc0fea399acb12edbf8a628ba8d2312f583bdbdb3335635db062fa98cf71fca4",  
                "sha256:fe460b922ec15dd205595c9b5b99e2f056fd98ae8f9f56b888e7a17dc2b757e7"   
            ],  
            "markers": "python_version < '3.8' and implementation_name == 'cpython'",   
            "version": "==1.4.1"    
        },  
        "wrapt": {  
            "hashes": [ 
                "sha256:b62ffa81fb85f4332a4f609cab4ac40709470da05643a082ec1eb88e6d9b97d7"   
            ],  
            "version": "==1.12.1"   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Was your `Pipfile.lock` possibly out of sync with your `Pipfile`? Heroku installs _exact_ versions defined in from the `Pipfile.lock`, not loose ones from the `Pipfile`. How have you been adding dependencies to your `Pipfile` on your local machine?

Comment: I install normal dependencies with `pipenv install <name>`, I also tried `pipenv lock` and `pipenv sync` before pushing

Comment: Well there's not much we can say with the information you've provided. It's all guesswork. You'd have to show us the `Pipfile` and maybe the `Pipfile.lock`.

Comment: Sorry yes, updated the question with Pipfile and Pipfile.lock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this, it turns out that Pipenv itself had an update where the syntax changed slightly, see:
[Pipenv install does not install everything from Pipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539443/pipenv-install-does-not-install-everything-from-pipfile/63546581#63546581)
for fix