# Pipenv install does not install everything from Pipfile

Tags: python, pipenv, pyenv

I am running this on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install:

`pipenv install`
with Pipfile:

```
$ cat Pipfile
[packages]
Django = "*"
django-split-settings = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
django-compressor = "*"
django-libsass = "*"
Brotli = "*"
django-htmlmin = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
wagtail = "*"
wagtail-metadata = "*"
wagtail-blocks = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
django-tz-detect = "*"
wagtailcodeblock = "*"
django-taggit = "*"
django-taggit-templatetags2 = "*"
django-fontawesome-5 = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
wagtail-robots = "*"
wand = "*"

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[packages.whitenoise]
extras = [ "brotli",]

[packages.django-storages]
extras = [ "dropbox",]
```

then running:

```
$ pipenv run pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
django-storages 1.9.1
pip             20.2.2
setuptools      49.6.0
wheel           0.35.1
whitenoise      5.2.0
```

it only installs whitenoise and django-storages for some reason, how can i fix this?

additional information:

```
$ which python
/home/maks/.local/share/virtualenvs/personal-website-lhNGB4ub/bin/python

$ which pip
/home/maks/.local/share/virtualenvs/personal-website-lhNGB4ub/bin/pip

$ pyenv which python
/home/maks/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/bin/python
```

This issue has popped up recently after developing on windows for a while, when it happened I switched to just using a requirements.txt file instead, but now I want to go back to using pipenv.

as far as I can tell it's not a problem with the encoding of the file or the line endings, and I am uncertain as to when/why exactly this started happening.

EDIT:
running `pipenv install django` will install django properly but the pipfile and pipfile.lock remain identical meaning that this is not a problem with the Pipfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX:
So what worked was removing the pipfile and manually re-installing each package with `pipenv install`, this resulted in a slightly different looking pipfile, by the looks of it what caused me this issue, was an update to pipenv itself... have a look:

old Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[packages]
Django = "*"
django-split-settings = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
django-compressor = "*"
django-libsass = "*"
Brotli = "*"
django-htmlmin = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
wagtail = "*"
wagtail-metadata = "*"
wagtail-blocks = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
django-tz-detect = "*"
wagtailcodeblock = "*"
django-taggit = "*"
django-taggit-templatetags2 = "*"
django-fontawesome-5 = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
wagtail-robots = "*"
wand = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"

[packages.whitenoise]
extras = [ "brotli",]

[packages.django-storages]
extras = [ "dropbox",]
```

after manually re-installing each package on fresh environment:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"

[packages]
django = "*"
django-split-settings = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
django-compressor = "*"
django-libsass = "*"
brotli = "*"
django-htmlmin = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
wagtail = "*"
wagtail-metadata = "*"
wagtail-blocks = "*"
django-tz-detect = "*"
wagtailcodeblock = "*"
django-taggit = "*"
django-taggit-templatetags2 = "*"
django-fontawesome-5 = "*"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
wagtail-robots = "*"
wand = "*"
whitenoise = {extras = ["brotli"], version = "*"}
django-storages = {extras = ["dropbox"], version = "*"}
gunicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Installing from this pipfile using `pipenv install` worked fine, and all packages were installed.

I am not exactly sure why this all happened, perhaps it's a bug in pipenv, or maybe there is no backward-compatibility. If anyone knows please let me know.

If you want to fix this without reinstalling every package, you can simply replace bits looking like this:

```
[packages.whitenoise]
extras = [ "brotli",]
```

and convert them to this format:

```
whitenoise = {extras = ["brotli"], version = "*"}
```

after doing that run `pipenv install` and all your dependencies will be installed correctly

I submitted an issue on the Pipenv repository: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4433

Comment: I can relate of the same problem but with "url" instead of "extras" the fix works also in this case.

Comment: This drove me mad for a while. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

The only pattern I see here is, that whitenoise and django-storages is not part of the top [packages]. Maybe, just to get closer to the source of the problem, try to take a package, for example gunicorn, past it to the bottom and do something like this:

```
`[packages.gunicorn]
 extras = [ "",]`
```

Also, PythonPATH works a bit weird on Windows, make sure thats not the problem when you switched. Maybe have a look at your native Python installation if the packages appeared there and not in your env :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Adding packages like this makes them install, but obviously I want my normal packages to install correctly. I also developed this on Ubuntu before I switched to Windows temporarily. I just freshly installed pyenv and then Python 3.7.8 and pipenv, I installed it via pip, and i see no way that the installation could have gone wrong, although I don't know how I'd check that.

Comment: I run the following:
`
(personal-website)$ python -m site
...
'/home/maks/.local/share/virtualenvs/personal-website-lhNGB4ub/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
...

$ python -m site
  ...
 '/home/maks/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
...

$ ls cd /home/maks/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
`
and
`
ls /home/maks/.local/share/virtualenvs/personal-website-lhNGB4ub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
`
and could not see the packages in either site-packages

Comment: I cannot find the packages in system Python either, they just don't install, it's like pipenv doesn't see them.

Answer (score -1):

*`setuptools`, `pip` and `wheel` are a part of python package and come preinstalled. Just keep them updated to the latest version.*

Comment: That does not answer the question. I did not install them manually through Pipenv.